# How to find out if the PIC microcontroller is good or dead?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, microchip, testing, damage

I am working with a PIC microcontroller (part number dsPIC33FJ64MC802).

Previously I was able to program it fine. But today, I have powered the PCB which contains the PIC microcontroller, then suddenly smoke came out somewhere near to the microcontroller.

After this incident, I have connected the PICKIT3 programmer and then I got the error:

> "Target ID(XXXXX) doesnt match the device ID(XXXXX)".

I intuitively thought I might have damaged the microcontroller. After this I measured the VCAP voltage: it is giving around 2.5 volts as mentioned in datasheet.

If microcontroller damaged means, how it gives VCAP voltage? How to conclude whether the microcontroller is damaged or not? Correct me if I am wrong.

Microcontroller datasheet: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/70291G.pdf

Answer (score 3):

If your microcontroller turns into a smoke emitter, it's no use asking if it is damaged or not. It is damaged.

But if it wasn't the MCU itself, you should try to locate what is the problem and determining from where actually the smoke came from.

It is possible that something else is now shorted or damaged but the MCU isn't. For example a short circuit on a connector could damage a regulator and now your MCU has no supply. Or if the regulator broke in a way that it passes 12V directly to your MCU, then it is damaged.

Measure voltages nearby MCU, see where the smoke came from, measure what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

It’s possible that the core voltage regulator is working, but something else on the chip is damaged.

It’s also possible (but perhaps less likely) something else on your board (such as a TVS) is damaged and maybe the chip is still okay, or perhaps they are both toast. No way for us to know.

Examine the board closely and see if you can identify the burned part. If it’s the MCU that was emitting smoke, then **at  least** that part needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

> If microcontroller damaged means, how it gives VCAP voltage?

If you look in the datasheet, it's not exactly guaranteed* that a damaged microcontroller has to be completely dead, including the voltage regulator. If anything, the regulator is quite robust since it has large geometry devices, so it might survive some fault current that other parts of the microcontroller won't.

*That's tongue-in-cheek of course. But the assumption that "if a chip is dead, it's all dead" is just weird. Many chips - especially older ones - fail partially. Say a 4-bit DRAM chip may suddenly get one bit stuck or unreliable. Now, they fail that way without any external faults, so it is a bit different than when the magic smoke escapes. But still: faults can cause anything end everything, just like undefined behavior in C or C++ programs can. No guarantees that the program must crash, just as there are no guarantees that the regulator will always die from overstress.